# Tool for automated testing of WPF Application

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for an automated testing tool for our WPF application. I've tried QTP and am not interested in its price. I am looking for a lower priced solution with some good reviews. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [White](http://www.codeplex.com/white)?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework can be used for automated testing. My last experience with it was not particularly enjoyable, but it's an option